# Possible to record audio output streaming from other apps?

Tags: iphone, ios, streaming

Looking to record any audio that streams on my device. Are there any apps that are capable of doing this for ALL audio? (Im not interested in radio station apps that record radio stations only).

I am willing to jailbreak the phone to make this work.

Running ios 10.2 on iphone6

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of anything on the phone itself but getting audio out of an iphone and onto something that can record is possible.

Using AirPlay and [Airfoil Satellite](https://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/) (or your Airplay receiver of choice) you can get the audio to your Mac. Then using Audio Hijack (as mentioned by Kalamalka Kid) on your Mac you can record it.

Not the most ideal setup but it works.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can, using Quicktime Player, with the possible exception of certain DRM'd apps like Netflix. See here for instructions: https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-record-your-iphones-screen-and-audio-using-a-mac/

Comment: Answers should be self-contained and not just refer to an external source (which can disappear anytime). Please summarize the relevant content of the linked page directly into your answer (and leave the link for reference).